# Remove word and character from strings

Tags: sed

Is there a method to remove this string

```
"name": "_acme-challenge",
```

and left only with :

```
_acme-challenge
```

I read that I can use sed but I don't understand much how to go with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this very simple command:

```
echo '"name": "_acme-challenge",' | cut -d'"' -f4
```

this is the output:

```
_acme-challenge
```

I divided the string using `"` as field separator and using only the 4th field.

...and that's all! :)

PS: if you have the `"name": "_acme-challenge",` as a Shell variable, then you can use the following one:

```
NEW_VARIABLE=$(echo "$YOUR_VARIABLE" | cut -d'"' -f4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The next command could be used for string if the searched pattern could be anywhere, not only in 4th part of the divided string. It's more position independent.

```
echo '"name": "_acme-challenge",' | grep -o '_acme[^"]challenge*'
```

Everything before `_acme` and after `challenge` would be stripped.

```
$ echo '"number": "1", "name": "_acme-challenge", "something": "else"' | grep -o '_acme[^"]challenge*'
_acme-challenge
```